# Ratio test isnt monotonic

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $S_n := \sum_{k=0}^n a_k$. Under the assumptions that $a_n$ is positive, decreasing and passes the ratio test, then I know that for every $0 \leq n < \infty$ the following holds:

$$
R_n = S - S_n \leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{1 - b_n},
$$

if $b_n = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ **decreases** to L and

$$
R_n = S - S_n \leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{1 - L},
$$

if $b_n = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ **increases** to L (Proof in https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EstimatingSeries.aspx).

But, if $b_n$ is not monotone, can I have another way to limit $R_n$?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? What are you trying to prove or understand.

Comment: What the ratio of terms says about the error.